# Integrate Ratchet (PHP library) to already-existing webserver (Arch Linux, Nginx, PHP)

Tags: php, nginx, https, websocket, ratchet

I'd like to integrate [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) Library to my existing PHP-based website. I'm using Nginx & FastCGI for PHP.

Since my website is HTTPS-based, I have to use wss rather than ws. I'm wondering what I should change in my nginx.conf file!

```
worker_processes 2;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {

    include mime.types;
    rewrite_log on;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 256;

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /srv/http/myApp;
        server_name my-site-name.net;
        index index.php;
        #charset koi8-r;
        #default_type  text/html;
        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        #error_page  404              /404.html;
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #

        location ~ \.php$ {
            #default_type text/html;
            #add_header Content-Type text/html;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        include /srv/http/myApp/nginx.conf;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site-name.net/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site-name.net/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-site-name.net/chain.pem;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        if ($scheme != "https") {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting.

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/75